# datetime - a bug or a feature?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
now = datetime.now()
then = datetime(2001, 1, 1)
delta = now-then
print(delta)
print(delta.days, delta.seconds)
print(delta.hours, delta.minutes)
```

gives the following errors:

> > 6959 days, 16:09:27.863408
> >
> > 6959 58167
> >
> > AttributeError: 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'hours'
> >
> > AttributeError: 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'minutes'

is it a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A feature: [`timedelta` objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) only have `.days`, `.seconds`, and `.microseconds`.

I suppose this is because days are sometimes irregular (e.g. due to leap seconds, and date arithmetic can account for that), while minutes and hours can be readily computed from seconds. Could have been slightly nicer, but still would have a few corner cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can check all attributes in this way:

```
>>> dir(delta)
['__abs__', '__add__', '__bool__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__divmod__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__floordiv__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__mod__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__neg__', '__new__', '__pos__', '__radd__', '__rdivmod__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rfloordiv__', '__rmod__', '__rmul__', '__rsub__', '__rtruediv__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__sub__', '__subclasshook__', '__truediv__', 'days', 'max', 'microseconds', 'min', 'resolution', 'seconds', 'total_seconds']
```

There are no "hours" and "minutes"

Comment: I know that, but why? There are 'microseconds' but no 'hours' and 'minutes'?! BTW, this is not the only inconsistency I started noticing...

Comment: @newcomer I think the explanation given by 9000 is good enough. I have no additional comments. You can get “hours” from “seconds” and it is very easy.